# Get parent of button on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Actual, I layout like the picture [image]

When I click into OK button, I want to layout window like picture as below
[image]

I have an idea to resolve is get parent of button OK (is tableLayoutPanel 3) then use

> controls.Clear()

finally, I will add more tableLayoutPanel 4 (into TableLayooutPanel 0) + two buttons OK and Cancel (into TableLayoutPanel 4) like picture,but did'nt success.
I coded in OK button click Even as below:

```
Button bt = sender as Button;
TableLayoutPanel fatherBt = bt.Parent as TableLayoutPanel;
fatherBt.Controls.Clear();
```

What do you think about my idea. If not clear, pls give me your idea for this case.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why do you want to change the parent of the button? Why don't you just add another panel? If the name is important to you, you can easily change the name (however I cannot see how it may be useful). What is the problem that you are trying to solve? It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: In fact, when I click on button OK , my application will run `action 1` then my application maybe create new tablelayoutpanel and certainly, it have two button OK and Cancel, but, action of them isn't `action1`. so, I think, I must remove them and re-build it => it makes me confused

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Does `action 1` create a new `TableLayoutPanel` ? I don't see any reason why you need to move your buttons to a new panel. Keep them in `TableLayoutPanel3`, create and append `TableLayoutPanel4` under `TableLayoutPanel2`

Comment: If its in the Same `form` you can create the `Layout` like Second Picture. Then make `TablePanelLayout3` property `visible` to `false`. On **OK** `button_Click` you can make `TablePanelLayout3` property `visible` to `true`. Will this not work for you. ?

Comment: @Linh what is it you are trying to achieve? add more layouts on click of OK button?

Comment: @JackLe : The reason makes me remove buttons to a new panel is I don't know append `tablelayoutpanel 4` under `tablelayoutpanel2`  =))

Comment: @SH7: I know that, but when my form have two tablelayoutpanel, my buttons are on a different task than form has three tablelayoutpanel => It made me remove button and re-build it

Comment: @Licentia: No Licentia, When OK button is pressed, my source code will perform its task, Sometime, it add more layout, sometime it remove layout -> Task of button will be different

Comment: When my form have two tablelayoutpanels, buttons have stask is `action1`. When buttons is pressed, my source code will run `action1`. When success, my form must have new button, but this new button will have new stask is `action2`. `action2` is different `action1`

Comment: @Linh is it the same form? in what conditions will it decide what to do?

Comment: @Licentia: Yes, it is one.